# Pi Pico: Software Reset using the C SDK?

Tags: c, pi-pico

I'm looking for a method/function to be able to reset a Raspberry Pi Pico via programming, using the Pic's C SDK. Is this possible?

There is a way to do it using python using machine.reset() but I can't call that from within C (I think). I also want to avoid wiring a transistor into the ciruit. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see another way than using the watchdog. The example in the SDK documentation looks similar to this:

```
void software_reset()
{
    watchdog_enable(1, 1);
    while(1);
}
```

This busy waits 1ms until the chip is reset by the watchdog.

The time could be reduced to 1us by writing the value 2 directly to the watchdog LOAD register. I don't know if writing zero would lead to an immediate reset, it could also be that the counter wraps around to 0x00FFFFFF.

You could also use the scratch registers of the watchdog to detect a software reset.

Comment: The necessary include is #include "hardware/watchdog.h"

Answer (score 0):

A more raw solution at the level of working with registers.

```
void software_reset()
{
    *((volatile uint32_t*)(PPB_BASE + 0x0ED0C)) = 0x5FA0004;
}
```